# Check if email is valid or already exist in Symfony 3.2

Tags: php, symfony

Please respect me I am new in symfony, and I want to validate form if valid and or already exist. The user is able to submit form and save the data in database, the problem is the user is able to submit duplicate email at the same time. How do I do this.

```
namespace SwipeBundle\Controller\Backend;

use SwipeBundle\Entity\Company;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\EmailValidator;

   public function addAction(Request $request)
    {   
        $company = new Company;

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($company)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('prefund_wallet', TextType::class)
            ->add('telephone_no', TextType::class)
            ->add('mobile_no', TextType::class)
            ->add('address', TextareaType::class )
            ->add('email_address', EmailType::class)
            ->add('website', TextType::class)
            ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();


        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $name           = $form['name']->getData();
            $prefund_wallet = $form['prefund_wallet']->getData();
            $telephone_no   = $form['telephone_no']->getData();
            $mobile_no      = $form['mobile_no']->getData();
            $address        = $form['address']->getData();
            $email_address  = $form['email_address']->getData();
            $website        = $form['website']->getData();
            $ip             = $request->getClientIp();

            $now = new\DateTime('now');

            // Check if email is valid
            $emailValidator = new EmailValidator();

            if(!$emailValidator->isValid($email_address, new Email())) 
            { 
              $form['email_address']->addError(new FormError('Invalid email')); 
            }           

            $company->setName($name);
            $company->setPrefundWallet($prefund_wallet);
            $company->setTelephoneNo($telephone_no);
            $company->setMobileNo($mobile_no);
            $company->setAddress($address);
            $company->setEmailAddress($email_address);
            $company->setRegistered($now);
            $company->setIp($ip);
            $company->setWebsite($website);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager();
            $em->persist($company);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'notice', 'Company has been added.'
            );

            die("Redirected");
        }

        return $this->render('Backend/Company/create.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, some didn't read the words "new to symfony"...

First thing to do is set your e-mail to unique in your entity:

```
/**
* @var string
*
* @ORM\Column(name="email_address", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
*/
private $emailAddress;
```

Don't forget to execute `doctrine:schema:update --force`

Next step would be what you already did, set the type in the FormType.
Btw, you don't need to add `TextType::class` everywhere...

```
->add('email_address', EmailType::class)
```

And to check if email isn't from some anonymous yopmail or stuff like that, you will need to create a service which will check the e-mail domain.
You can also do it in the FormType as well, but you will need to do it for every FormType, thus a service would be better. You can easily find here about how to create a service. If you really need help, comment, and I will write down an exemple.

You can find a list of those anonymous email services a bit everywhere, google is your friend.

Comment: ->add('email_address', EmailType::class), this only adds browser validation.  An Assert should be used in the entity to be sure to only save valid emails.

Answer (score 1):

you can  check email validation   directly on entity level.

Look at  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html

And  to check is unique  use

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

If  you do it  right - it'll  be only 2  lines (2 asserts)   of code  in  Entity